# When using cURL, can the target page detect the exact url?

Tags: php, curl

Lets say we have our own script here:

> https://example.com/random_name/script.php

```
// Code inside the script.php
$url = 'https://foo.com';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

As you can see, the link above gets content of this domain:

> https://foo.com

I know *foo.com* can see `example.com` and it's `IP Address`!

but **Questions** is, can foo.com (the page we're getting content from) also by *any methods* detect this exact part: 
`/random_name/script.php` is making the request? does it depend on using TLS?

Comment: As long as your server does not send the information, no. It has absolutely nothing to do with TLS.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I was thinking they can put some javascript in the code, maybe using `XMLHttpRequest()` to send the exact URL back, but that needs a web browser to get executed. so, no `tricky methods` exists that can detect the exact URL if web browser isn't involved?

Comment: What URL do they want to send back? They got nothing. Also webbrowser block that AJAX request as long as the target website doesnt allow it with CORS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page (server/application) can have all the information in the request. If the request (in your example - `script.php`) will not send the extra data (`/random_name/script.php`) the page the receive the request will not have it.

If you want to receiving end (*foo.com*) to know about it you can use the referer header:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://example.com/random_name/script.php");
```

And this way - *foo.com* can view that information in the `referer` header.

Comment: I was thinking they can put some javascript in the code, maybe using `XMLHttpRequest()` to send the exact URL back, but that needs a web browser to get executed. so, no `tricky methods` exists that can detect the exact URL if web browser isn't involved?

Comment: I wanna make sure they CAN'T get the exact URL with any tricks, so sending CURLOPT_REFERER is not the case here.

Comment: So the answer is that if you only send a request - the receiving end can't know anything about the original URL you sent the request from (only the IP, not even the domain).